# Asynchronous defaultValue from Redux for React-Quill

Tags: reactjs, redux, redux-saga, quill

React-Quill Version 1.3.1

Hi guys. I need help.
I use redux-saga and redux-saga-router for preload data from database and when i redirect my page, for instance, from '/' to '/workspace' we catch the certain action and load the data. And after that i need provide to user opportunity to Edit text into Quill so i use defaultValue. But as we know, re-render in defaultValue does not working so i have only my initial state, although in the same time in ReduxDevtools i can see updated state.

If i change defaultValue to value - user cannot do any changes in editor area.

*From react-quill*

> Pass defaultValue instead of value if you need to use DOM or Quill APIs to imperatively manipulate the editor state. In this "uncontrolled" mode ReactQuill uses the prop as the initial value but allows the element to deviate after that. The onChange callback still works normally.

somebody know how i can resolve it ?